# Use HDF5 from intel fortran on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, hdf5, intel-fortran

I would like to create a HDF5 dataset from a fortran90 program compiled with intel fortran 2011 on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010

Can I use prebuilt binaries or how do I build new ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded thanks to High Performance Mark:
Here was what I did (not sure that everything is necessary):

- Download and install cmake
- Download and install HDF5 [Windows (32-bit), Compilers: CMake VS 2010 C, C++, IVF 12, RWDI]
- Set environment variable: HDF5_DIR=C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.x/cmake/hdf5
- Download HDF5 source
- Make empty build folder
- Run CMake(cmake-gui) from start menu
- Set source (HDF5 source) and destination (empty build folder)
- Configure
- Set generator to Visual Studio 10
- Specify native compilers [C:"", C++:"", Fortran: "<..>\ifort.exe"]
- Check: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and HDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN
- Configure
- Configure
- Generate
- Open <..>\build\HDF5.sln in Visual Studio 2010
- build project ALL_BUILD

And finally

- Create new project with a Fortran example
- Linked the generated libs exactly as High Performance Mark describes

I hope some else can use the reciepe.

Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

I build from source, the available built binaries use the MS C/C++ compiler while I want to build with the Intel compiler, and they are built with Intel Fortran v12.x while I'm using v14.x.  I won't say that you can't use the binaries, but I've had enough of a struggle in the past to persuade me to build my own.

I've also had struggles with trying to build them directly from VS and now use CMake.  Your first step ought to be to install CMake and figure out how to use it.  You don't need much knowledge of the tool and the effort will be repaid several times over.  You can, for example, also use CMake to build Szip and Zlib, if you want them.  An increasing amount of this sort of software is made available with CMake support so you won't necessarily only use it for HDF5.  For example, I use CMake to build VTK for Windows too.

Once you've done that and generated the solution/project files with CMake you can load up the solution in VS and build `ALL_BUILD`.  This generally works smoothly, though I have found that some projects need to have their linkages adjusted and sometimes I get spurious flags in the command-lines sent to the compilers. Then, running VS in administrator mode, you can build the pseudo-target `INSTALL`.

I see that HDF5 1.8.12 is now available, I'll download and build it, let you know how I get on.

*Compiling and Linking*

If you just want to use HDF5 include the line

```
  USE, NON_INTRINSIC :: hdf5
```

at the appropriate place in your source file(s).  Then, under `Project Properties | Fortran | General | Additional Include Directories` insert the path to the location of `hdf5.mod`.  That should get you compiling.

To link, under `Project | Properties | Linker | General | Additional Library Directories` insert the path the location of the `.lib` files.  Then, under `Project | Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies` insert `hdf5_fortran.lib`.

You should then be able to compile and link your program. If you want to use additional facilities, such as the HDF5 Table Interface, then `use h5tb` and figure out the linkages.

And consult the documentation.  See, for example, `../HDF5-1.8.12/release_docs/USING_HDF5_VS.txt`

Comment: Thank you. I have now done what I think you suggest and have now a file: bin\release\libhdf5.lib (but dependency walker claims that it is not a 32 or 64 bit windows module). Does it sound correct and how do I use it

Comment: Not really.  You should at least have also `hdf5_fortran.lib` and, nearby in the file system, `hdf5.mod`, so that you can `use hdf5` in your source files.  You link the `.lib` file(s) in the normal VS way.

Comment: Ok, now C:\hdf5stuff\build\bin\Release contains hdf5.lib,hdf5.dll,hdf5_fortran.lib,hdf5_fortran.dll etc. and C:\hdf5stuff\build\bin\fortran\Release contains hdf5.mod etc. but the linking goes wrong. Which files and folders should be linked where?