# Use HDF5 from minGW on windows

Tags: compilation, makefile, linker, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to compile and link to HDF5 with a Fortran program, but I'm getting a run-time error. I've followed closely the procedure described in the answer to this question

[Use HDF5 from intel fortran on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048938/use-hdf5-from-intel-fortran-on-windows)

I've set PATH in the environment variables instead of setting them in visual studio. I moved all of the generated .mod and .lib files to the mod and lib folders in my project folder.

From the command prompt, my compiler config looks like

```
 gfortran --version
 GNU Fortran (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 4.9.2
 gmake --version
 GNU Make 3.81
```

And my makefile looks like

```
 ifdef SystemRoot
     PATHSEP2 = \\
 else
     PATHSEP2 = /
 endif
 PS = $(strip $(PATHSEP2))

 OBJ_DIR = obj
 MOD_DIR = mod
 LIB_DIR = lib

 FC      = gfortran
 FCFLAGS = -I$(MOD_DIR) -g -Wall
 FLFLAGS = -I$(MOD_DIR) -L$(LIB_DIR) -l$(LIB_DIR)hdf5_fortran

 SRCS_F = testHDF5.f90

 TARGET = testHDF5

 all: $(TARGET)

 testHDF5: testHDF5.f90 
  $(FC) -o $@ testHDF5.f90 $(FLFLAGS)

 $(OBJ_DIR)$(PS)%.o: %.f90
  $(FC) $(FCFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

I've changed the hdf5_fortran.lib to libhdf5_fortran.lib because of what I read here

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use

When I run gmake, I get

```
 gfortran -o testHDF5 testHDF5.f90 -Imod -Llib -llibhdf5_fortran
```

And when I try to run the executable, a window pops up that says "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

This link

http://www.solveinweb.com/solved-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application/

Suggests that it is due to incompatibility of 32-bit to 64-bit. I'm using a 64-bit machine, and I did download a 32-bit version of CMake, but only because there doesn't seem to be an available version for 64-bit machines. In addition, this link

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039375.html

Suggests that it shouldn't matter. So my question is, where did I go wrong? Are there any glaring mistakes with what I've shown so far?

UPDATE:

I found out that the runtime error was due to not specifying a path, in this case HDF5_DIR. In the USING_HDF5_CMAKE document, it says to specify the environment variable

```
 HDF5_DIR=C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.8.x/cmake/hdf5
```

Which fixed the problem of the application crashing at the very start. But now, I'm getting the error

```
 HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.14) thread 0:
   #000: C:\Users\Charlie\Downloads\CMake\hdf5-1.8.14\src\H5D.c line 167 in H5Dcr
 eate2(): not a datatype ID
     major: Invalid arguments to routine
     minor: Inappropriate type
 HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.14) thread 0:
   #000: C:\Users\Charlie\Downloads\CMake\hdf5-1.8.14\src\H5D.c line 415 in H5Dcl
 ose(): not a dataset
     major: Invalid arguments to routine
     minor: Inappropriate type
```

I suppose the first error

```
 HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.14) thread 0:
   #000: C:\Users\Charlie\Downloads\CMake\hdf5-1.8.14\src\H5D.c line 167 in H5Dcr
 eate2(): not a datatype ID
     major: Invalid arguments to routine
     minor: Inappropriate type
```

Is the most important one since that may trigger later ones. According to this thread

http://hdf-forum.184993.n3.nabble.com/HDF5-Fortran-Fail-to-execute-of-a-basic-F90-program-td4026778.html

It is suggested that the same compiler is used to build the library as building the fortran source code (if I'm not mistaken). During the build using CMake, I specified to use MinGW, which I believe is used during both builds, right?

Again, any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted hdf5 support in regards to this problem

```
 Platform/OS:
 Windows 7

 Product/Version:
 HDF5, Latest download

 Description:
 Hi, I'm having trouble getting HDF5 working on my windows machine with fortran. Below is an outline of what I've done, and after I show the error I get. 

 1.1) Download and install CMake, Windows (Win 32 Installer) from http://www.cmake.org/download/ 

 1.2) I did not add CMake to the system PATH, because it was too long. 

 1.3) I manually added "C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/bin" to the PATH (for user)
 in computer->properties->advanced system settings->environment variables 2.1) Download and install HDF5 

 2.2) I manually added "C:/Program Files/HDF Group/HDF5/1.8.14/cmake/hdf5" to the PATH (for user) in computer->properties->advanced system settings->environment variables 

 3.1) I created a new, empty, directory (/Project/) and copied HDF5Examples-0.1.1-Source.zip and HDF518 Examples.CMAKE to it. 3.1) Downloaded hdf5-CMakeWindows.zip from http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/cmakebuild.html and unzipped
 file to find a folder named CMake. 

 3.2) Opened CMake GUI, set Source Code Dir = CMake/hdf5-1.8.14 folder 

 3.3) Set Where to build binaries Dir = /Project/ (project folder containing HDF5Examples-0.1.1-Source.zip and HDF518 Examples.CMAKE) 

 4.1) In the CMake GUI, I pressed Configure, (selected MinGW and default from the 1st and 2nd drop down respectively), Configure. Checked BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and HDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN. Configure, configure, generate. 

 4.2) I navigated to the bin directory of the CMake folder and copied the library files, .dll files, and .mod files to an empty test folder (/test_HDF5/), where I separated them into lib/mod folders. 

 4.3) I created a makefile which, if done correctly, linked the .lib files. 

 4.4) I compiled the files and linked the libraries and there seemed to be no errors, nor warnings. When running the testHDF5.exe I received the following error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application. I believe this is a configuration issue, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. 

 I'm very new with linking libraries and I'm just trying to use HDF5 as a data exporting tool with my existing fortran code. Any help is greatly appreciated. 

 Sincerely, Charlie Kawczynski
```

And their response was, as of April 14 2015, that MinGW is not supported:

```
 Hi Charlie,

 We do not support MinGW at this time. The developer had tried
 building with Fortran and was not able to get it to work.

 We do have a user forum where you can post questions. However, others
 have posted issues about MinGW and Fortran that have not been resolved. :(

 For information on the HDF Forum, see:
    http://www.hdfgroup.org/services/community_support.html

 -Barbara
```

Hope this helps others.