# Building HDF5 libraries for Visual-Studio 2017 with Intel Fortran Compiler 19.0 on Windows 10 with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, fortran, hdf5

I am trying to build HDF5 Fortran libraries for VS 2017 (Community, Version 15.9.11) with CMake (Version 3.15.5). To do this, i have downloaded the necessary files and followed the instructions on this site: https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/support/Building+HDF5+with+CMake

The CMake-hdf5-1.10.5.tar.gz file contains a CTest Script that should automatically build the libraries. The only thing i changed from the default options in the "HDF5options" file was i set the Build_Fortran Bool to on, as the default would not build the libs for Fortran.

Then i ran the script with the command

```
ctest -S HDF5config.cmake,BUILD_GENERATOR=VS201764 -C Release -V -O hdf5.log
```

The building was executed but not everything worked. It seems that most of the Fortran related stuff didn't build correctly and failed the automatic testing. Also i didn't manage to compile anything in the automatically created VS Projects in the build.

All the failed tests can be seen here: 
http://txt.do/1k82z

And i uploaded the entire build log here.
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=50578175097329210274

I don't know what I did wrong. My goal is to write HDF5 files with Fortran with my Hard and Software so if someone can suggest an entirely different solution to achieve that, it would also solve my problem.

Edit: I tried using cmake-gui as suggested in the link provided by a kind commentator and after setting source path, and build path I let it configure, then i ticked HDF5_BUILD_FORTRAN and left everything else as it was and let it configure again. The following errors appeared:

```
SOVERSION: 103.1.0
SOVERSION_TOOLS: 100.1.2
SOVERSION_CXX: 103.1.0
SOVERSION_F: 102.0.0
SOVERSION_HL: 100.1.2
SOVERSION_HL_CXX: 100.1.3
SOVERSION_HL_F: 100.0.4
SOVERSION_JAVA: 100.4.0
Checking for InitOnceExecuteOnce:
Warnings Configuration:
Could NOT find Perl (missing: PERL_EXECUTABLE) 
Cannot generate headers - perl not found
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:746 (set):
  implicitly converting 'INTEGER' to 'STRING' type.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

The Fortran compiler identification is Intel 19.0.0.20181018
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe
Check for working Fortran compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe  -- works
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
Determine Intel Fortran Compiler Implicit Link Path
Determine Intel Fortran Compiler Implicit Link Path -- done
Checking whether C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe supports Fortran 90
Checking whether C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2019/windows/bin/intel64/ifort.exe supports Fortran 90 -- yes
Detecting Fortran/C Interface
Detecting Fortran/C Interface - Found GLOBAL and MODULE mangling
Testing Fortran sizeof
Testing Fortran sizeof - OK
Testing Fortran c_sizeof
Testing Fortran c_sizeof - OK
Testing Fortran storage_size
Testing Fortran storage_size - OK
Testing Fortran ISO_FORTRAN_ENV
Testing Fortran ISO_FORTRAN_ENV - OK
Testing Fortran RealIsNotDouble
Testing Fortran RealIsNotDouble - OK
Testing Fortran iso_c_binding
Testing Fortran iso_c_binding - OK
CMake Warning (dev) at config/cmake_ext_mod/HDFUseFortran.cmake:195 (set):
  implicitly converting 'flags' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:826 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) at config/cmake_ext_mod/HDFUseFortran.cmake:196 (set):
  implicitly converting 'flags' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:826 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Fortran compiler ID is Intel
Testing Fortran c_long_double
Testing Fortran c_long_double - OK
Testing Fortran c_long_double
Testing Fortran c_long_double - Fail
Detecting Fortran REAL and INTEGER KINDs
Testing Fortran REAL and INTEGER KINDs - Fail
CMake Error at config/cmake/HDF5UseFortran.cmake:124 (file):
  file failed to open for reading (No such file or directory):

    C:/ProgramData/HDF5Libs/pac_fconftest.out
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:835 (include)


CMake Error at config/cmake/HDF5UseFortran.cmake:128 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:835 (include)


CMake Error at config/cmake/HDF5UseFortran.cmake:129 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:835 (include)


CMake Error at config/cmake/HDF5UseFortran.cmake:130 (list):
  list GET given empty list
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:835 (include)


CMake Error at config/cmake/HDF5UseFortran.cmake:134 (message):
  Failed to find available INTEGER KINDs for Fortran
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:835 (include)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/ProgramData/HDF5Libs/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/ProgramData/HDF5Libs/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: This --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048938/use-hdf5-from-intel-fortran-on-windows/ is now a few years old, but may provide some useful input.

Comment: When possible, please post the **actual text** for the error in your question post. Please do not *only* post the links.

Comment: @squarekittles I know, unfortunately the texts in question are quite long, especially the build log. I will try to find out what part could be interesting and include it as text.

Comment: Where on your computer (which directory) did you extract the downloaded files?  Where are you trying to build hdf5?  The paths in the error messages are unusual.

Comment: The code source lies in a path like this -> C:/ users/myusername/documents/programs/hdf5something/..  (note: my username does not contain spaces, it does contain special characters though a "ö" and a "-" . I censored it in the Logfiles i uploaded. The reason i have a programs folder in my documents is just to store old installers etc. The first time i tried to build was in a subfolder of the source folder and the second time i created a folder in C:\programdata\ calling it HDF5Libs. I can't tell you exactly right now because i'm on my phone. But I paid attention to no spaces in the path.